# Disconnecting after remote IP change via powershell

Tags: powershell

With the following powershell code, I am able to modify the static IP of a remote windows 7 machine.

```
Write-Host("Modifying IP... ")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { 
           & {
           $adapter = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "Index = 7"
           $adapter.EnableStatic($Using:NewIP,"255.255.255.0")
           } }
```

This is the last part of my script. After changing the IP, the connection is lost. That is expected. Thing is that the script still tries to reconnect for about 4 minutes and then it gives up. The output is shown below:

```
Modifying IP... 
WARNING: The network connection to 10.1.1.50 has been interrupted. Attempting to reconnect for up to 4 minutes...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to 10.1.1.50 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to 10.1.1.50 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to 10.1.1.50 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to 10.1.1.50 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to 10.1.1.50 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to 10.1.1.50 ...
WARNING: The reconnection attempt to 10.1.1.50 failed. Attempting to disconnect the session...
WARNING: Reconnection attempt canceled. Please repair the network connection and reconnect using Connect-PSSession or Receive-PSSession.

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Because that is what `ping / Test-Connection` will do unless you tell it not to. Once the command is fired off, that session/request has to complete. The default response per session/request is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Send a command without waiting for any result

If you just want to send a command to a remote computer and don't want to wait for any result, just use the parameter `-InDisconnectedSession` of Invoke-Command.

```powershell
Write-Host('Modifying IP... ')
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -InDisconnectedSession -ScriptBlock { 
    $adapter = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter 'Index = 7'
    $adapter.EnableStatic($Using:NewIP, '255.255.255.0')
}
```

---

### Send a command without waiting for the result *immediately*

If you require a result from the remote computer after some time, but don't want it immediately, then you have to work with the remote PSSession while still using the parameter mentioned above.

```powershell
$newIP         = '172.168.0.1'
# a friendly name for the session. Useful for 'Get-PSSession'
$psSessionName = 'ipAddressChange'

$invokeCommandParam = @{
    SessionName           = $psSessionName
    ComputerName          = $RemoteMachine
    Credential            = $Cred
    InDisconnectedSession = $true
    ScriptBlock           = {
        $adapter = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter 'Index = 7'
        $adapter.EnableStatic($Using:NewIP, '255.255.255.0')
    }
}

$psSession = Invoke-Command @invokeCommandParam 

# wait some seconds for the remote machine to execute the command
Start-Sleep -Seconds 7

Write-Host 'Waiting for remote machine ' -NoNewline
while (!(Test-Connection $RemoteMachine -IPv4 -Quiet -TimeoutSeconds 2)) {
    Write-Host '.' -NoNewline
}

# receive output from remote machine
$result = Receive-PSSession -Session $pSSession
$result

<# 
If Receive-PSSession above does not work due to IP address change, try to get the PSSession again:
    $psSession = Get-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -Name $psSessionName
    $result    = Receive-PSSession -Session $psSession
    $result
#>
```

**For more information see:**

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_disconnected_sessions
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command

Answer (score 0):

You can use $null or [void], not to see the response at all, but it will still occur, or, you need to use try/catch or if /then to hard exit the script if you don't want to see it,
or, specifically, code for how many responses you want. So this...

```
ping /n 2 /l 1000 localhost
```

or this...

```
Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName localhost
```

Comment: You mean I have to put `Test-Connection` after the invoke command? Or inside the script block?